# vim key sequence as function argument

Tags: function, vim

I want to execute the command `"yiw:s/\<<C-r>"\>/<C-r>"/g<Left><Left>"` by key sequence.
So I make a mapping

```
    nnoremap <F7> yiw:s/\<<C-r>"\>/<C-r>"/g<Left><Left>
```

This mapping copy the word under cursor, then the string :s/\<">/"/g" (where " are substituted by the copied word) appears in the command line and the cursor in the command line is at the end of replacement statement.

I also want to save cursor position before this command and restore after.

```
  function! SafeCommand(cmd)
let line = line('.')
let col = col('.')
// execute cmd here 
call cursor( line, col )
  endfunction
```

How to do that?

Comment: 1) you mapped `F` then `7`, not `<F7>`. 2) if you want to do a `:s/../../g` you need put `<CR>` there 3) even if there was a `<CR>`, your left left doesn't make sense either, because after substitution, your cursor would be at the beginning of that line.  4) I didn't understand what are you trying to do...replace the word under cursor with same word? can you explain it  a bit in your question?

Comment: after firing your mapped command, pressing `Ctrl-O` could bring you back to the old position. Also, you don't have to copy the current word, in command line `<c-w> (:h <c-w>)` will copy the word under cursor. do you want that function anyway?

Comment: Thx for tips. But yes, I still want to know how to write such function.

Comment: If I were you, I would in function accepting user's input (the replacement) by `input()`. I am not sure if passing a string as keysequence work in function, and stopping at command line and waiting for user finishing the cmd then pressing enter, then function continues.... at least `normal ` or `execute ` don't..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd just put the entire (complex) command in a function, and invoke that function from the `:nnoremap`. But that doesn't work for incomplete commands, like the template `:substitute` that your mapping represents. For that, you need to include the save / restore parts into the command-line (though that's ugly):

```
:fun! Save()
    let s:line = line('.')
    let s:col = col('.')
:endfun
:fun! Restore()
    call cursor( s:line, s:col )
:endfun
:nnoremap <F7> yiw:call Save()<Bar>s/\<<C-r>"\>/<C-r>"/g<Bar>call Restore()<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```